# call c++ dll from java

Tags: java, c++, dll

I am using c dll in java, I want to load c Dll in java, I use JNA library but I get error “Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.”, please tell me how can I solve my problem, if you have another solution please guidance me.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class ConectorTJna {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        IConectorT lib = (IConectorT) Native.loadLibrary("add", IConectorT.class);
        int teste=lib.add(4, 5);
        System.out.println("RESULT: " + teste);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing some DLL required by your *add.dll*. Try to check in the *Event viewer* -> *Windows Logs* -> *Application* to see if there is more info in here.

Comment: Thank you, it shows this error “Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.” In event viewre

Comment: Are you using a Debug build for your add.dll ? If so, it's bad, very bad. Try using a Release build of your dll.

Comment: thank you, it does not take that error, now it takes this error"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'add': The specified procedure could not be found."

Comment: Well, seems like the function "add" could not be found in the dll. Did you export it ?

Comment: thank you,yes i use this int APIENTRY(dllexport) add(int a, int b);